# Creating an object every time I call a function

Tags: javascript, html, json

[Codepen with my working application](http://codepen.io/pablocgdev/pen/XKozyR)

I have the following:

```
    <button onClick="createBox()" id="box">Create Box</button>
```

and this is my function:

```
function createBox()
    {
        var obj = {
        "1": "",
        "12": "",
        "123": "",
        "1234": "",
        "12345": "",
        "123456": ""
    };  
    console.log(obj)

        document.getElementById("box").onclick = function () {

            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.className = 'new-box';       
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);

        }
    }
```

I want to create a new box with a new object every time I click the button. After that, I would like to click one box and fill that object box with my select list:

```
<select id="asdf" class="selectVal">
    <option value="1">asdf</option>
    <option value="2">asdf1</option>
    <option value="3">asdf2</option>
</select>

<select id="asdf" class="selectVal">
    <option value="1">asdf1</option>
    <option value="2">asdf2</option>
    <option value="3">asdf3</option>
    <option value="4">asdf4</option>
</select>

<select id="asdf" class="selectVal">
    <option value="1">asdf1</option>
    <option value="2">asdf2</option>
    <option value="3>asdf3</option>
    <option value="4">asdf4</option>
    <option value="asdf5>asdf5</option>
    <option
```

I have the following code for filling the object:

```
    function getSelectedItems() {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.selectVal, input');
        var results = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var element = elements[i];
            var strSel = '';
            if (element.tagName == 'SELECT'){
                strSel = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
            }
            else if (element.tagName == 'INPUT'){
                strSel = element.value;
            }

            results[element.id] = strSel;
            console.log(results)
        }


        strSel = JSON.stringify(results, null, 4);
        var blob = new Blob([strSel], {type: "application/json"});
        var url  = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.download    = "file.json";
        a.href        = url;
        a.textContent = "Download JSON";

        console.log(strSel);
        document.getElementById('json').innerHTML = strSel;
        document.getElementById('download').appendChild(a);
```

So I need to adapt my code to create independent boxes with independent objects that I can fill through my selects and inputs to download the JSON.

Comment: As an aside, `= new Object()` is redundant because you immediately throw that empty object away and assign `obj` equal to the object created via the `{}` literal.

Comment: You are right, just was testing with it, Updated.